# Wordpress custom url rewrite htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url:
http://www.ficss.it/dettaglioevento/?id=5000&id_tipologia=1&t=corso-tecnico-treibball

and i wanto to obtain this url:

http://www.ficss.it/dettaglioevento/5000/1/corso-tecnico-treibball

i tried to use this htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^dettaglioevento/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /dettaglioevento/?id=$1&id_tipologia=$2&t=$3 [L]
```

but don't work. The platform is worpress

Thanks

Comment: Maybe check the order of your regex, this should probably be _before_ WordPress's